# How install older Goclipse version? Cannot install Goclipse 16.1 on Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2)

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, version, eclipse-mars, goclipse

-Is there a way to install an older version of Goclipse, compatible with my Eclipse 4.5.2?
-Or, is there a way I can manually install the missing dependencies (see below)?

I am using Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2). When trying to install Goclipse, I only see version 16.1 which according to the Goclipse documentation requires Eclipse 4.6 or later.

The error I currently get when trying to install Goclipse 16.1 is:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GoClipse 0.16.1.v201607061938 (goclipse_feature.feature.group 0.16.1.v201607061938)
  Missing requirement: GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 5.0.0.201606062011 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 5.0.0.201606062011) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: GDB DSF Debugger Integration Core 5.0.0.201607151550 (org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb 5.0.0.201607151550) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.launchbar.core 2.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GoClipse Eclipse Debug 0.16.1.v201607061938 (com.googlecode.goclipse.debug 0.16.1.v201607061938)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb [5.0.0,6.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: GoClipse 0.16.1.v201607061938 (goclipse_feature.feature.group 0.16.1.v201607061938)
    To: com.googlecode.goclipse.debug [0.16.1.v201607061938]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this URL as a Eclipse Software Site:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoClipse/goclipse.github.io/0.16.0/releases/

It should allow you to install 0.16.0 (or a diff version if you change the URL)

Comment: Wonderful! This totally resolved my issue.
I am now successfully using GoClipse 16.0 on Eclipse 4.5.2.
Thanks!